# Populate dropdown from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to simply populate a dropdown with a JSON response from an API.

```js
let dropdown = $('#LA_picker');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType%3DnhsTrust%3Bdate%3D2020-12-20&structure=%7B%22name%22:%22areaName%22,%22code%22:%22areaCode%22%7D&format=json&page=1';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $.each(data.data, function(key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(entry.name).html(entry.name));
    console.log(entry.name);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="LA_picker" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

When opening the webpage, the dropdown is there with "Choose State/Province", but there are no other options. Note I have put `console.log(entry.name);` in there to check the console output, which is successful and gives the names of all the entries as expected.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `<option selected disabled>`; then you wouldn't need `dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);` Note that `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, so depending on where that code is run, it could be running the success function first, then the code that empties the dropdown and adds the first option. A [mre] would help in distinguishing what is going on.

Comment: Code shown works fine

Comment: Thanks for the responses... On further inspection, the <option>'s are all being added as expected (I can inspect element and see them there), however they are just not physically displaying on the dropdown itself for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: You must be instantiating some kind of plugin like Select2 or another, before the results of the request are received.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Seems the class "selectpicker" is what breaks it. This is from the Bootstrap-select plugin. Unsure how to get them working in harmony, as I need the search feature from the bootstrap-select plugin.

Comment: Please can you share a JSFiddle with the plugin added

Comment: Ok... Then remove that class and add `dropdown.selectpicker();` AFTER the `$.each` loop (not inside)... But inside the `getJSON` callback. See [documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Seems the class "selectpicker" is what breaks it. This is from the Bootstrap-select plugin.

Since there is a bootstrap selectpicker instance on that `<select>` element... The instance must be instantiated after the results from the ajax request are received.

You actually instantiate usint the `selectpicker` class. Remove it and add `dropdown .selectpicker();` in the `getJSON` callback, AFTER the `$.each` loop.

The ajax request takes a bit of time to resolve... And selectpicker is adding some new elements to the DOM, based on the content of the original `<select>`. That is why the plugin has to be instantiated in the `getJSON` callback.

[bootstrap-select documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

```js
let dropdown = $('#LA_picker');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType%3DnhsTrust%3Bdate%3D2020-12-20&structure=%7B%22name%22:%22areaName%22,%22code%22:%22areaCode%22%7D&format=json&page=1';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $.each(data.data, function(key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(entry.name).html(entry.name));
    console.log(entry.name);
  })
  dropdown.selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="LA_picker" data-live-search="true"></select>
```